# Ubuntu Mate global shortcut for hiding/showing application

Tags: 16.04, emacs, ubuntu-mate

I am an Emacs user, and would love to be able to hide and show emacs from whatever I am doing, just as seen in Guake/Tilda.

I am running Ubuntu Mate 16.04, and using compizconfig-settings-manager I can assign a hotkey to open Emacs, but when I press it again, it opens a new window rather than switching back to the old window.

Is there any way of doing this in Mate? I would really like it to be a single key press as well, probably an F-key.